# Elixir / Erlang Dialyzer : Why behaviour callback's param type should be subtype instead of supertype?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, dialyzer

I have a behaviour X and a callback function with parameter type:

```
%{a: any}
```

Module Y implements behaviour X and the callback function in implementing module Y has parameter type:

```
%{a: any, b: any}
```

Dialyzer doesn't like that and complains:

```
(#{'a':=_, 'b':=_, _=>_}) 
is not a supertype of 
#{'a':=_}
```

This implies dialyzer attempts to determine if callback parameter's type in implementing module Y is a supertype of param type in behaviour X. In other words, it asks:

> Is behaviour X's callback param type `%{a: any}` a subtype of 
>   implementing module Y's param type `%{a: any, b: any}`?

**Why does dialyzer expect behaviour callback's param type to be a subtype instead of a supertype?**

In the context of programming language type theory, [subtype is defined](http://www.cs.pomona.edu/~kim/FOOPL/chap5.pdf) as:

> type S is a subtype of a type T, written S <: T, if an expression of
>   type S can be used in any context that expects an element of type T.
>   Another way of putting this is that any expression of type S can
>   masquerade as an expression of type T.

In light of the definition above, it makes sense to me if parameter type of behaviour callback is `T` and that of implementing module is `S`. Because implementing module still keeps the behaviour contract. However, I'm clueless as to why dialyzer expects the other way around.

Please help me understand this.

Note: This question is a follow-up but independent of another SO question [Erlang (Elixir) Dialyzer - confusing supertype error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246998/erlang-elixir-dialyzer-confusing-supertype-error).

Comment: `Because implementing module still keeps the behaviour contract.` I don't think it does. Now you have a module that you say implements `X` but no one can actually call the function with `%{a: any}` as the behavior says because your implementation also requires `b: any` in the map.

Comment: Even though implementing module Y requires additional `b: any` in the map, it's good to allow any operation that can be performed on the original type specified by behaviour X. It respects width subtyping rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Width_and_depth_subtyping

Comment: "it still allows all operations on the original type specified by behaviour X" According to the behaviour I should be able to pass `%{a: 1}` to all the implementors of X but I can't do that to Y because it requires an additional field `:b`. The reverse is fine -- if X requires `%{a: any, b: any}` and `Y` requires `%{a: any}`, that's fine because I can call it like the behaviour says and `b` will be ignored by `Y`.

Comment: Just had an aha moment! Didn't think from that angle. Thanks a lot. This is very useful. Can you please put that in an answer so I can accept it? We're more likely to read an accepted answer than to read comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialyzer is correct. If there is a behaviour `X` with a callback of type `%{a: any}`, the user should be able to call that function of any module that claims to implement this behaviour with e.g. `%{a: 1}`. Your module's function takes `%{a: any, b: any}` which is a *subtype* of `%{a: any}`, which means that function cannot be called with `%{a: 1}` anymore which does not comply with the behaviour.

On the other hand, if the behaviour's callback had the type `%{a: any, b: any}` and your module's function had the type `%{a: any}`, that would have been fine because `%{a: any}` is a supertype of `%{a: any, b: any}` and your module can be called with `%{a: 1, b: 2}` -- it can just ignore the extra field.